# Using AfterScenario with TickSpec

Tags: f#, gherkin

I have a feature file like so:

```
Feature: Viewing revenue

Background:
Given invoices
| Date     | Amount |
| 1/1/2010 | 200    |
| 1/1/2011 | 300    |

Scenario: Total revenue
Then the total revenue is
| Label | Revenue |
|       | $500    |

Scenario: Total revenue by year
When I choose to view it by "Year"
Then the total revenue is
| Label | Revenue |
| 2010  | $200    |
| 2011  | $300    |
```

I want to run some cleanup code after the execution of each scenario.  I have a function decorated with the AfterScenario attributes as shown:

```
let [<AfterScenario>] ``Drop Invoices`` () =
  Invoices.removeAll
```

The function does get called, but only once, and only when I reload the project through NUnit's gui runner.  Subsequent runs of the tests, without reloading the project, do not invoke the function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The call to `Invoices.removeAll` seems to be missing a parameter, you may need to add [()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd483472.aspx).

[TickSpec](http://tickspec.codeplex.com/) expects attributed methods to return unit, so you may need to pipe the result to ignore. You can check the type of the `Drop Invoices` function by hovering over it, it should say unit -> unit, if it doesn't try this:

```
let [<AfterScenario>] ``Drop Invoices`` () =
  Invoices.removeAll () |> ignore
```

There was an [issue](http://tickspec.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/234cb04f8b3d) prior to the November 2012 release of TickSpec where AfterStep and AfterScenario functions were not called if an exception was thrown when executing a step in a scenario. This is fixed in the latest source and the assembly is available via [CodePlex](http://tickspec.codeplex.com/releases/view/98432) or [Nuget](http://nuget.org/packages/TickSpec).

If you have more than one function marked as AfterScenario and any of them raise an exception then subsequent AfterScenario methods will not be called. Ideally your BeforeSceanrio and AfterScenario functions should not throw.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response.  Passing unit to `removeAll` did the trick.  I'm still unclear on that, as removeAll was defined as:  `let removeAll = Invoices.RemoveAll()` (where Invoices refers to a MongoDB Collection).  I had to add a unit parameter: `let removeAll () = ...` to complete the puzzle.